# Creating Indexed MongoDB during installation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am creating an installation for a system using .NET and MongoDB. I wrote a batch to ensure indexes on DB but it would not work unless you have collection created. Is it a bad practice to do smth like:

```
db.Customers.save({username:"mkyong"})
db.Customers.remove({}) 
db.Customers.ensureIndex({SystemId:1,CampaignId:1,LocalIdentifier:1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`createCollection`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/createCollection+Command) command:

```
db.createCollection("Customers")   
db.Customers.ensureIndex({SystemId:1,CampaignId:1,LocalIdentifier:1})
```

Comment: I am sorr but I also can't really find how to create a db with the specified name. It seems logical that smth like createDB should exist

Comment: `use my_database` should do the trick (it depends in which context you run your script, but I assume it's plain Javascript which could also be executed at the `mongo` console)